# How can I make redirect after mail send with PHPMailer

Tags: php

I am trying to get PHP Mailer Script to redirect after the message has been sent.

```
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message'] = 'There were errors with your form, please refer to the warnings!';

    } else {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success! Your message was sent. I will contact you shortly.';
    }
}

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can suppose you want to redirect the user to **Welcome.php** when Email is sent successfully.
So you need to change the location with HTTP header.

Here an example

```
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message'] = 'There were errors with your form, please refer to the warnings!';

    } else {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success! Your message was sent. I will contact you shortly.';
    header('Location: Welcome.php');
    }
}

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tech Spot for help. Unfortunately it didn’t work.